# Off canvas menu not filling entire height of page

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have a site that is using an off canvas menu for the navigation. When you click on the boat house link, it slides out anther layer with a really long list. One this layer the background color does not extend all the way to the bottom. I have the `HTML` and `body` tag both set to `100%` as well as the menu itself set to `100%`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the link to the site: http://shoreline.gonzbergagency.com/

Comment: Can we see the specific code in order to pinpoint the issue?

Comment: You can add `overflow-y:scroll` to the `div` containing that long list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the background color to the nav menu ul:

```
.mp-menu ul {
    background-color: #002e5f;
}
```